# Событие onfocus, срабатывает после второго раза фокусировки на элементе input

Tags: javascript, html

Наверно проблема в событиях `click` и `focus`, что-то с очередью. Но решения не придумал.

Полей и форм будет много. Ставить обработчик на каждое поле не эффективно. Хотя работает и логика по другому сделана. Вот и решил сделать делегирование, но застрял.

Решение надо без jQuery.

Спасибо.
[Код](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-ptolemy-y99f5?file=/src/index.js) + HTML

---

```
function animateLabels(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        if (e.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
            e.target.onblur = e => {
                console.log("blur", e.target);
                if (e.target.value == "") {
                    e.target
                        .closest("span")
                        .previousSibling.classList.remove("label-top");
                }
            };
            e.target.onfocus = e => {
                console.log("focus", e.target);
                e.target.closest("span").previousSibling.classList.add("label-top");
            };
        }
    }
    document
        .querySelector(".form")
        .addEventListener("click", (e) => animateLabels(e));
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы на каждый клик по форме вешаете обработчики событий. Сделайте это один раз, при загрузке формы.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko согласен, эти михаели ваще не видят что функция добавляется каждый кликц